# array_multisort not working

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have two different arrays

**$player_details**

```
Array ( 
[83] => Array ( [number] => 2 
                [name] => Mario Goetze 
                [position] => Sturm
                [age] => 37 ) 
[96] => Array ( [number] => 4 
                [name] => Lukas Podolski 
                [position] => Torwart
                [age] => 24 ) 
[66] => Array ( [number] => 1 
                [name] => Marco Reuss 
                [position] => Langzeitverletzt
                [age] => 24 ) 
[359] => Array ( [number] => 99 
                 [name] => Inge Schmidt 
                 [position] => Mittelfeld
                 [age] => 23 )
 )
```

**$array_positions**

```
$array_positions = array("Torwart", "Abwehr", "Mittelfeld", "Sturm", "Spielberechtigte Talente (A-Jugend)", "Langzeitverletzt");
```

I wanted to sort $player_details after $array_positions to get the right order for my footbal team

```
array_multisort($player_details["position"],$array_positions);
```

But that's not working. What can be wrong?

Comment: Can you share your current output?

Comment: `$player_details["position"]` does not exist, if anything it's `$player_details[..]["position"]`. Further, the contents of the `$array_positions` array and the positions in the `$player_details` array don't correspond at all (no, PHP doesn't translate from German to English automatically). In other words, you're just randomly throwing things together here which won't magically just work. That's what's wrong. Maybe read this? http://stackoverflow.com/q/17364127/476

Comment: Sorry I changed the positions to their correct name. I saw this article but I can't take out anything constructive for me, it's just really to much for me. Can you maybe just give an advice how I can connect both arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you try to sort an array by an individually sort algo. look at the php function `usort`

https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.usort.php

```
usort($player, function($a, $b) use ($array_positions){
    $aPos = $a['position'];
    $aVal = array_search($aPos, $array_positions);
    $bPos = $b['position'];
    $bVal = array_search($bPos, $array_positions);

    if( $aVal == $bVal ) return 0;
    return ($aVal < $bVal) ? -1 : 1;
});
```